# Xamarin.Forms Portable cant access to ADO Open Command

Tags: c#, mono, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

Good Morning,
My application is being constructed in Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise using Xamarin.Forms Portable.

The application target devices are : Windows Universal (10), Ipad , Android.

So I reach the situation that I need database, and I've started using the ORM Sqlite, but I've noticed that I must declare all the query mapping, so I'm thinking on changing to ADO ( Mono.data.sqlite ).

I've copied the  example code from Xamarin and tryed to install via nuget the Mono.Data.SQL, but i did not have access to .Open() property, and could not create the database or connect to an existing one.

Then I've tried creating a new test project with Vs2015 + Xamarin.Forms PLC and add the Mono.data.sqlite and System.Data directly in the references, with that way I did gain access to .CreateFile, .Open , but i receive this  error :

"Reference to type 'Component' claims it is defined in 'System', but it could not be found

[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5KWi.png)
Right now I'm still looking in the internet, but did not found any good answer of why this is happening.

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1):

First off, Xamarin Forms UWP is in Preview and has known issues when going release when compiling for native. It will all be fixed and go into production eventually (hopefully this year) but just raising that.

Second I recommend using SQLite PCL. https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net.Async-PCL/

Xamarin have an article on it: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/databases/

Yes you don't get a powerful ORM like Entity Framework (which you actually do get on UWP (EF7+ only, in RC1 now), but not Xamarin.iOS or Xamarin.Android). But its still the preferred way to go. And you can use SQLite Extensions to help https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions

You can google any of the above, there are plenty of resources on everything mentioned (sans EF7)

**Update**

Yes you can get it to automatically map back to an object, SQLite PCL.NET does this for you and you can call the methods with generics.

```
    // Set a variable to your SQLiteAsyncConnection
    database = sqlLite.GetAsyncConnection();

    // Call a query and have it map back to the object type
    public async Task<List<T>> QueryAsync<T>(string queryText, params Object[] args) where T : class, new()
    {
        return await database.QueryAsync<T>(queryText, args);
    }

    // Or here is another helper function
    public async Task<List<T>> GetAllAsync<T>() where T : class, new()
    {
        return await database.Table<T>().ToListAsync();           
    }
```

e.g.

```
    public class MyTable
    {
        public string ColumnName { get; set; }
    }


    await GetAllAsync<MyTable>();
```

Comment: thanks for the fast reply.
With Sqlie PCL, we can perform normal querys without using the mapping tables like in ADO ?
I want to use the DataReader and not the ORM version eheheheh .

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know of any DataReader like ADO for PCL. With SQLite you can perform queries with a SQL string query.

Comment: yes you can perform queries with SQL string query, but you must define the mapping ,and if I create a query that have 20 fields  that is going to be used 1 time, I must create the mapping, or there is any automatically way to do it ?
The project that I'm  starting will have many query's with custom mapping.

Comment: I've tried your solution and used custom names, and it worked :D .
but in the second function GetAllAsync i'm not able to make it work .

But still, thanks for all the  help.